# Does a set of the second category have positive measure?

Tags: measure-theory

A subset of a topological space $X$ is called nowhere dense in $X$ if the interior of its closure is empty.

A subset of a topological space $X$ is called the first category (or meagre) in $X$ if it is a union of countably many nowhere dense subsets.

A subset of a topological space $X$ is called the second category (or nonmeagre) in $X$ if it is not of first category in X.

Let $G$ be a locally compact Hausdorff topological group, we know that there exist a Haar measure on $G$.

My question is:

Does ther exist a Borel subset(generated by open subsets) $B$ of the second category in $G$, and this set $B$ has the measure zero?

Comment: You can use [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) to construct one.